# How to Fix SSL certificate error when want to push to GitHub using git bash?

Tags: git, bash, ssl, github

I am trying to push to GitHub a simple web application using git bash on Windows 8. But when i do git push origin master it says "fatal: unable to access 'https://********.com/****/******.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate".

Could someone help me with this issue, without disabling the SSL.

Comment: the ssl certificate is in the Git directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix the error by giving your SSL certificate. You can do this by either:

- Editing your Git config file (in Linux `~/.gitconfig`) and add:

  ```
  [http]
      sslCAinfo = <path to your key>
  ```
- Executing the following command:

  ```
  git config --global http.sslCAinfo <path to your key>
  ```

Comment: raviolicode, did you mean for example my certificate is in Program Files. Then I will have to type sslCAinfo = C:/ProgramFiles/certificate.crt . And then git config --global http.sslCAinfo C:/Program Files/certificate.crt .  Is that correct???

Comment: @Octtavius only one of the above is needed. For example: `git config --global http.sslCAinfo <path to your key>` will add the configuration to your `~/.gitconfig`, so there's no need to add that line to the `gitconfig` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanation !