# Unable to push to GitHub from PC (after not having problems): SSL certificate

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am a new git/github user and have encountered the following

> error fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/myusername/my-repo.git/': SSL certificate problem:
>   self-signed certificate in certificate chain

This has me confused because I have made pushes to my remote GitHub repository before without issue. I confirmed that the origin is correct and got the same error message upon running `git push` and `git push -u origin master`. I have seen similar questions which don't quite seem to match my situation as either deal with a situation in which the repo is attempting to be cloned (while I am trying to upload) or have not used 'https' (or some other issue).

There is a post which suggests an answer ([How to Fix SSL certificate error when want to push to GitHub using git bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017376/how-to-fix-ssl-certificate-error-when-want-to-push-to-github-using-git-bash)) but I am really very confused as I have never had to explicitly deal with keys before. And no tutorial I have viewed have mentioned them.

Any thoughts? I am on a Windows 10 system using git bash. I am on the same home network I have used to make successful pushes in the past.

Answer (score 3):

similar issues happen to me when cloning a repo you can try this

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

https://confluence.atlassian.com/fishkb/unable-to-clone-git-repository-due-to-self-signed-certificate-376838977.html

Update:
Well if you aren't familiar with openssl then you need to get and use it.

unset ignorance

```
git config --global --unset http.sslVerify
```

If you do have it and already created a Certificate then try verifying it just to see what it says

```
openssl verify domain.crt
```

Renew it if it has expired

```
openssl x509 -in domain.crt -noout -enddate
```

If you don't have one, generate your server credentials first

```
openssl req \
   -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domain.key \
   -out domain.csr
```

Now create it

```
openssl x509 \
   -signkey domain.key \
   -in domain.csr \
   -req -days 365 -out domain.crt
```

put it into pem file

```
cert.pem
```

Now import it

```
git config http.sslCert ~/path/to/ssl/cert.pem
```

Then check it with

```
git config --global --list
```

Sources with a few more minor details

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/openssl-essentials-working-with-ssl-certificates-private-keys-and-csrs
- [configure Git to accept a particular self-signed server certificate for a particular https remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072376/configure-git-to-accept-a-particular-self-signed-server-certificate-for-a-partic)

Comment: Your solution worked but I am concerned about what has actually caused the issue in the first place and what I have done to 'resove it.'

Comment: expanded it largely let me know if it looks like i left out some steps

Answer (score 0):

Set git to trust your certificate using `http.sslCAInfo` parameter

Configure your certificate as:

```
git config --global http.sslCAInfo <path to your .pem file>
```

You can check your config by:

```
git config --list
```

Comment: @Shadow43375: Try this to update your config . It worked for me

Answer (score -1):

just do some step

git config --global user.email "your email address"
git config --global user.name "username"

and firstly make sure that your pc ssh key is added to your git account in setting->ssh key section